T-SQL alias '=' not working in AWS Redshift
I found that aliasing using the '=' format is not working in AWS Redshift. Is there any possible way to resolve this without changing on existing query?
In SQL Server:
select fileid AS ID from tableA     -- Working 
select [ID] = fileid from tableA    -- Working

In AWS Redshift:
select fileid AS ID from tableA    -- Working 
select [ID] = fileid from tableA   -- Fails, will return ERROR: column id does not exist in table A.


I know nothing of Redshift, but it appears according to its documentation (1, 2) it only supports expression [ AS column_alias ] syntax.

This seems to be an MSSQL speciality, because neither MySql nor Oracle seem to support this syntax. So, I'd say stick to the standard and use AS alias . And no, typically there is no way to redefine the query syntax in existing products.

And it is a deprecated feature since almost 20 years.... "String literals as column aliases" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-deprecated-features-object?view=sql-server-ver16

[ID]=fileid is a boolean expression, returning TRUE if the column [ID] value is equal to the column fileid value. (ISO/ANSI SQL-2023, optional feature T031, BOOLEAN data type.)
But you have no column [ID], hence the column id does not exist error.
Conclusion, do this the ANSI/ISO SQL way:
select fileid AS ID from tableA 


AWS Redshift is based on PostgreSQL and does not support this aliasing syntax.
Use the 'as' keyword or a simple space between the column name and its alias.
Like these
select fileid AS ID from tableA;

or
select fileid ID from tableA;

